# Rails: Youtube video (iframes) partials is showing up blank when rendered via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, iframe, youtube

In my Rails app, I list @trailers which are embedded youtube videos (in an iframe). Works fine except when I try to render via AJAX.

All the html is there, except the videos are just blank. If I inspect, I can see the proper video appears to be embedded but it's completely white.

Is this something to do with rendering iframes via Ajax or something?